# Is there a way to return a value from a try-catch block into a preexisting variable outside of the block itself?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I feel like this may be somewhat of a dumb question, but I've tried everything I currently know to do as a beginner of C# on this. Is there any way I can return a value into one I've already set to use elsewhere? Or am I just over-complicating this whole thing? Every time I try to set the already existing variable with one inside the curly brackets I get an error. Code I used below.

```cs
static double GetAmount()
{
    double amount;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter in the amount for the transaction: ");
        double amount1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        return amount1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool f = true;
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        while (f == true)
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the total in a proper format, no letters or spaces please. ");
                double amount1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                f = false;
                return amount1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex2.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
            }
    }
    finally
    {
        return amount;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: `I get an error` - could you please tell us _what_ that error is? it might be helpful in solving your problem. which, by the way, is a bit _unclear_

Comment: `try-catch` blocks aren't usually placed within a `catch` block.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/2-exercise-variable-scope

Comment: Welcome to SO!, since you say you want to simplify, perhaps you'll find the `Double.TryParse` Method helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two compilations errors and a warning. To understand them you must know that the finally-block is always executed before returning from the try- or catch-block. I.e., `return amount1;` would execute the statement in finally-block `return amount;`. But only one return-statement can be executed. Therefore, you get the message:

> CS0157 Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

and

> CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'amount'

because the variable is declared but is not assigned a value yet when return is called.

Also, you get the warning

> CS0162 Unreachable code detected

on the last code line, because the method will either be left by one of the previous return-statements or stay in the while-loop forever. Therefore, this last return statement can never be executed.

---

The bool flag `f` is redundant. There is no point in setting it to `true` before the return statement since the method is exited at the return-statement. This terminates the while-loop at the same time. If you want to exit the loop without returning, you can call `break;`.

Simplified version using try-catch:

```cs
static double GetAmount()
{
    Console.Write("Enter in the amount for the transaction: ");
    while (true) {
        try {
            double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            return amount;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.Write("Enter the total in a proper format, no letters or spaces please: ");
        }
    }
}
```

The statement `while (true)` introduces an endless loop. Endless unless it is left by `return`, `break` or an unhandled exception (or the frowned upon goto command).

A better alternative is to use the `TryParse` method that does not throw an exception

```cs
static double GetAmount()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the amount for the transaction: ");
    while (true) {
        if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double amount)) {
            return amount;
        }
        Console.Write("Enter the total in a proper format: ");
    }
}
```

This version has the same functionality as yours, is safe, is 3 times smaller and is much easier to read.

See also: [try-finally (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

Comment: Thanks for the help, got me rolling along smoothly on that. Getting started coding and man, it is way harder than I expected to be slammed by. Thanks again and you have a blessed day.

Answer (score -1):

```
    static double GetAmount()
    {
        double amount = 0;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in the amount for the transaction: ");
            amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool f = true;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            while (f)
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the total in a proper format, no letters or spaces please. ");
                    amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    f = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex2.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
                }
        }
        return amount;
    }
```

Comment: A code-only answer is not an answer.

Comment: I will learn it. Although I think in this case code > words.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. The OP does not know why he gets the errors and expects an explanation and an answer to his question.